# error: 'qAbs' was not declared in this scope

Tags: linux, qt, qwt

When I tried to install qwt manually, I got this error. How can I fix it? Thanks ahead. By the way, I also tried to install qwt by using command yum install, but after that I can't find where the qwt was installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpm -ql qwt` will tell you what files it installed. Please note that it's customary for RPM-based distributions to have `-dev` packages, so you're likely looking for the `qwt-dev` package.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum information you have to give are Qt and Qwt version.